# How do i select a row from MYSQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would like to retrieve a user's information from my database.
So far my code looks like this:

```
<?php
$database="myweekdatabase";
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root" ,"");//for wamp 3rd feild is balnk
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("$database", $con);

$User = $_SESSION['Email']; //Uses the email for the current user logged in
$query = "SELECT * FROM myweekprofiles WHERE Email = '$User' ";
$result = mysql_query($query);     
?>
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<h3>Edit Your Profile</h3>
<?php echo "<h3>" .$result; "</h3>" ?>
```

This is my output so far:

```
Resource id #5
```

Why am i getting this as a output?

Comment: You are getting `Resource id #5` as output because `mysql_query` returns `resource`(http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) upon success.  Refer to the documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Just a note: While sanitizing input fixes most problems (which you didn't do), you really shouldn't be using mysql_* functions in the first place. Something like PDO or Mysqli works better because of prepared statements, which are much more secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use foreach and fetch your data using mysql_fetch_array().

```
<?php
$database="myweekdatabase";
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root" ,"");//for wamp 3rd feild is balnk
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("$database", $con);

$User = $_SESSION['Email']; //Uses the email for the current user logged in
$query = "SELECT * FROM myweekprofiles WHERE Email = '$User' ";
$result = mysql_query($query); 
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);

foreach($result as $data){
echo "<h3>Edit Your Profile</h3>";
echo "<h3>" . $data['anyColumnYouWantFromThemyweekprofiles'] . "</h3>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you run a query like above you get a resource returned on success or false. You now need to use another method to get data from the resource you've received.

for example, to loop through results you can use something like this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    echo $row[0];
    echo $row[1]; //etc...
}
```

or if you want to use an associative array

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['field_name'];
    echo $row['other_field_name']; //etc..
}
```

Here's a link to all the methods http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php

Answer (score 1):

First, you shouldn't use mysql_ function that are deprecated.
Secondly, I think you should read some tutorials about php/mysql to learn how to manage a database.

If you don't know how to do that, you will have very hard time to go further in your code. 
There are plenty of tutorial about this. Try to find one about PDO or mysqli (that are much better than mysql_ functions)

About your code, you need to fetch the query. (`mysql_fetch_row` or `mysql_fetch_array` or `mysql_fetch_assoc`). And then ask for a column.
To see the result and to understand it, do this :

```
$array = mysql_fetch_array($result);
var_dump($array);
```